# Decryption with negligible error

Tags: encryption

In chapter 2 of Katz's Introduction to Modern Cryptography there is a formal definition of an encryption scheme.
As part of this definition, the decryption algorithm is required to be *perfectly correct*, and thereafter the book assumes the decryption algorithm is deterministic and never outputs a wrong decryption.

> Throughout the book, we assume that encryption schemes are *perfectly
>   correct*, meaning that for all $k\in\mathcal K$, $m \in M$, and any ciphertext $c$
>   output by $Enc_k ( m)$, it holds that $Dec_k (c) = m$ with probability 1.
>   This implies that we may assume $Dec$ is deterministic without loss of
>   generality (since $Dec_k(c)$ must give the same output every time it is
>   run). We will thus write $m := Dec_k(c)$ to denote the process of
>   decrypting ciphertext $c$ using key $k$.

My question is: If we allow $\mathrm {Dec}$ to produce a wrong decryption with negligible probability $\epsilon$ (this could be any value < 1, and by repeated application of $Dec$ we could get any level of confidence we want short of 1), would this affect the theory at all?

Would everything be the same, only with this additional chance of error? Or, if we allow these negligible mistakes, could there conceivably be some algorithm, that is 'better' (security or efficiency-wise) than anything possible with deterministic decryption?

Comment: Is the error random? That would seem to have a significant impact on the answer. If it is random, I don't see any security issues (or enhancements). If it isn't random, that could be a significant issue. Especially if triggering the error condition is not computationally hard to do.

Comment: Note that things probably would be more interesting if there's a (negliglible) probability (over all producable / possible ciphertexts) that the _ciphertext_ has some "bad" property which results in a wrong decryption but with the decryption still being deterministic.

Comment: @mikeazo For any specific input, the probability of correct decryption should be at least $1-\epsilon$. So theoretically by running the algorithm many times we could get arbitrarily high confidence in the decryption.

Comment: deniable encryption is not possible with perfect correctness, but things can be done with negligible probability of failures (there's a cool paper building that from LWE for example)

Comment: @AlonNavon, should the probabilities hold in an information-theoretic sense, a computational sense, or only under benign conditions?

Comment: @mikeazo Not sure of the difference. :\

Comment: @AlonNavon, let me take it from a different angle. When an error occurs, it is the case that on average half of the bits are flipped or are we talking a single bit flip?

Comment: @mikeazo Half of the bits.